# How to improve performance of keywords search?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, indexing, full-text-search

This is an interview question.

You have to write program, which finds all files that contain all given keywords. How would you pre-process the files to improve the search performance.

My answer:

I would use `Lucene` (or any other text-search engine). If I need to implement it manually I will build an index which maps the document words to the documents *ids*. We should probably implement that index with `B-trees`. An alternative is to use an RDBMS (`mySQL` or smth.) but it looks like an overkill to me.

Does it make sense? How would you answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, most of the time text-search engine is the way to go.. really easy to build and reliable. Just a minor detail here: most of the engines do OR search by default, so you have to specify that you want to match all the words.

If you have to build your own solution, yes, obviously you have to build mappings.. I would use a hash lookup and not a tree index, but your tree presumably won't be too big, so that's only a minor performance improvement. Still, I don't see the point of using a tree, you don't need the traversal features of it, you'll never search for the previous or next word..

More interesting details pop up when you actually check how you would use your data structure. Let's take an example search: `The pony he comes`. Intuitively, you wouldn't start the lookup with `the`, probably all the documents contain it (assuming they are english texts). `pony` is a good choice, and can easily narrow down your search. Most text-search engines contain a metric for this: how many documents contain that specific word. So based on that you start with the least frequent one, and check the words in increasing frequency order.

Once you managed to narrow down your search you start to realize your index doesn't work quite well... you still have the word `the` to check, and in your index that will show zillion of documents, so at this point it would be better to use a reverse mapping, from document to words (again, hash lookup or a trie). You check the handful documents to see whether they contain the remaining words.

Note: a lot of decisions here (how to store the mapping, simple or double mapping, btree/hash/trie/...) depend on the scale of the projects. Obivously you build something simple if you have to search in a couple of files, and build something different if you have to index all the files on github, or for gene sequence searching where even the index might not fit into memory...

Comment: Thanks, interesting. You suggest a hash map for index. Suppose the index does not fit in memory. How would suggest implement it?

Comment: What's the difference? Does it matter? You'll have buckets, and perhaps chains (depending on the hash type you use).. still, it's the same thing.. in memory you have a memory location, on a disk you have relative position in the file... In memory you have memory management, on disk you have to roll out your own one...